# Installing tweepy2 with Python 3.4

Tags: python, twitter, pip, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I successfully installed tweepy2 with Python 3.4 on Windows 7. But when I type `import tweepy`  (in the command line of Python) it gives me this message:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-2.3-py3.4.egg\tweepy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-2.3-py3.4.egg\tweepy\models.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-2.3-py3.4.egg\tweepy\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'quote'
```

How can I solve that error?

Comment: You installed Python using Tweepy2? Are you certain it wasn't the *other way around*?

Comment: yeah because i need to retrieve twitter data

Answer (score 0):

The Tweepy package is *not Python 3 compatible*. It will only work with Python 2.

The line that fails is:

```
from urllib import quote
```

which is only available in that location on Python 2. The [package documentation](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) clearly states this too:

> **Note** only Python 2.6 and 2.7 are supported at the moment. The Python 3 family is not yet supported.

You'll have to use a different package to interface with Twitter. The [Twitter Developer documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#python) lists several options:

- https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter lists Python 3.3 and 3.4 in the Trove metadata
- https://github.com/bear/python-twitter lists Python 3.3 support
- https://github.com/ckoepp/TwitterSearch lists support for Python 3.2 and up
- https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython states it supports Python 3

Comment: I used python2.7 as well but i had installation problem

Comment: Thank u Martijn i'll try again

Comment: @user3643380: if you are set on using Tweepy you'll have to solve those problems; it won't work on Python 3.

Comment: yeah i need to set another package, i'll read the Twitter documentation

Comment: after reading and searching I have installed tweepy2 with python2.7.8, on Mac OS. Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually i found that you have to install pypa/pip before install tweepy, i read that this library is missing from tweepy so you have to install it first.

Comment: Installing pip is not a requirement, you could also use `easy_install` to install third-party packages. It is not a dependency of `tweepy`, but rather a very convenient way to install packages.

Comment: yeah i did typed easy install but there was an error message, but after installing pypa/pip the error message hasn't shown

Comment: @user3643380 sure, but `pip` is just an installation tool still, not a dependency of `tweepy`. :-)